# how to test maps activity will visible in apk before publishing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I am doing project with map.i finished my map and published,but after publish the map is not visible.so i searched and find a method to get fingerprint for release fingerprint and generate API key.Now i am going to publish my app as a new one.But before going to publish,i want to check that whether map will visible after publish or not.Is there anyway to check it before publishing.Please help me.

Comment: Don't you have apk file for uploading to store with you? Install it and see whether map is visible or not.

Comment: @febi mathew ..thank you...for ur reply....i installed and checked now,it is showing.But i am having doubt whether it will visible after publishing in playstore or not.

Answer (score 1):

simply install the release build in an android device,if it works there it will work after publishing too.

Also note that google provides different api keys for debug and release builds.

So depending on the build and flavour , u need to use the corresponding keys in your app

Comment: @shyamyy if it worked for you ,please mark the answer as accepted for other peoples benefit